# Java, C/C++, C# девелопер - требования к железу

Tags: c#, .net, java, c++

Часто возникает тема по железу девелоперской машины. Понятно, что единого стандарта нет, но все же хотелось бы чтобы народ поделился своими рецептами по железу.

У меня стоит: Intel i5/3ггц/8гб с Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bits + к этому на виртуалке крутится Ubuntu Linux 32 bit и 64 bit + Windows 2008 Server. В основном кодирую на Java, с заходом в С/С++ и понужанием SQL или какого-нибудь веб-сервера.

Сколько пытался на лаптопе кодировать - ни фига не тянет, ровно как и на офисных машинках.

У кого что есть - делимся!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На работе Dual-Core 2.5Gh с 4Gb, Windows 7, два монитора. Работаю на Netbeans с Java проектами, плюс локально запущены MySQL и PostgreSQL, вполне комфортно, хотя Netbeans бывает бесит тормозами.

Дома десктоп Core 2 Duo 3Gh, 4Gb, Win7, бд вынесены в виртуалку с Ubuntu, никаких проблем с тормозами нет.

На ноутбуке неудобно программировать из-за маленького экрана, и на работе и дома 24" мониторы, что очень комфортно.

Answer (score 1):

Дома аналогично описанию компьютера в вопросе, только памяти 4GB, под VirtualBox Ubuntu 64-bit, Oracle-XE. Java в Eclipse. Все летает.

На работе  DualCore 2.7 GHz, Windows XP 32bit памяти 3 (стоит 4, но XP видит 3) виртуальная xubuntu 32-bit, остальное как дома. Если базу локально поднять, то плохо шевелится (проблемы с памятью). Когда надо, использую Oracle на сервере.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Comment: Слюнки текут =)

Comment: это железка на работе + 22"

Answer (score 1):

На работе laptop lenovo i5/2.67GHz, памать- 8Gb, Win7 64bit.
Java, app сервер, бд - всё летает ;)

Answer (score 1):

Дома работаю на ноуте (линукс, 4 гига оперативы) - работает отлично. Потому что соблюдаю несколько правил.

- не запускать google chrome. Не знаю почему - но он кушает очень много памяти. 20 вкладок - больше 2 гиг памяти.
- не запускать Thunderbird - он также любитель памяти и проца.
- Если нужно тестить вебсервер, то я использую для этого [acer revo](http://www.acer.ua/ac/ru/UA/content/series/aspirerev), который настроенный как сервер. Монитор, клавиатура ему нужны только если разкурочить ось. А так стоит себе в уголку и работает. Можно "соседей" попросить потестить. И не нужны виртуалки.

Comment: А у меня броузер "Интеренет" с ядром chromium на 20 вкладок с 800mb память поднял всего до 1,24 гб :)

Comment: я недавно выяснил причину потребления памяти. Это бага в 64битной версии. В 32битной - нет.
С другой стороны - гиг памяти на 20 вкладок - не много ли? Вот в опере 30 вкладок и 460 Мб, firefox - более 60 вкладок и 300мб памяти.

Comment: Opera уже давно на рынке Firefox-много разработчиков а Chromium на ранке недавно да и разработчиков пока немного может когда то Chromium догонит ато и перегонит Opera и Firefox!Имхо а может это будет Safari :)

Comment: Много разработчиков - не панацея. Почитайте Брукса (Мифический человекомесяц).
Да не нужно никого перегонять, просто багу нужно починить.

Answer (score 1):

Я однажды на нетбуке попробовал собрать ядро линукса. 4 часа собиралось.

Comment: А на компе из вопроса ? (оценка).

Comment: Ну, не знаю. На Core i7 четырехядерном 3.2 ГГц с ключом make -j около 15 минут занимает.

Comment: ubuntu не больше 15 минут обычно собирается.. у вас там к ядру компоненты управления межконтинентальных ракет добавлялись?)) шучу, верю =)

Answer (score 1):

Я на ноуте работаю - Acer Aspire 5552G (athlon 64 x2 2.1Ghz, 2GB RAM, Win 7 x86 )
пишу на C# в Visual Studio 2010. тянет неплохо. Иногда параллельно висит на виртуалке win server 2008 с базой Oracle 11g или Sql 2008. Тогда начинает иногда подтормаживать.)

Answer (score 1):

Интересно, зачем для программирования нужен мощный компьютер, кроме конечно тех, кто, как автор вопроса, запускает кучу виртуальных машин? Я программирую вообще на нетбуке и очень доволен. Конечно, я специально брал для этого самый мощный из нетбуков. Windows 7 + Visual Studio 2010 + VisualAssist летают. Полная сборка моего графического движка занимает 15-20 секунд. Всё что нужно для его написания поддерживается - вплоть до DirectX 11 и OpenGL 4.2.

Характеристики:

1. Двухядерный процессор AMD E-350 1.6 ГГц (оценка 3,7)
2. 3 ГБ оперативной памяти (оценка 5,5)
3. Жёсткий диск на 750 ГБ (оценка 5,9)
4. AMD Radeon HD 6310M (оценки 4,1 и 5,6)

---

Ну вот, кто-то пришёл и всех обминусовал. Зачем?

Comment: Да делать какому-то придурку нечего.

Answer (score 1):

У меня самый дешевый ноутбук с 15,6" экраном - Acer Aspire 5250.

Характеристики:
1. Двухядерный процессор AMD E-300 1.3 ГГц (оценка 3,2)
2. 2 ГБ оперативной памяти (оценка 5,2)
3. Жёсткий диск на 320 ГБ (оценка 5,9)
4. AMD Radeon HD 6310M (оценки 4,1 и 5,6)

Все летает на Windows 7, использую IDE Geany + постоянно запущен Chrome с 2-5 вкладками.

Answer (score 0):

У меня Win 95/i7/3.0 GHz/8 ГБ DDR3/Pascal. Все летает, и сам тоже! :)

Comment: круто, 95 винда видно с патчами:) она без бубна не запуститься на машинах, где больше 1гига памяти... (там на самом деле значительно меньше, но точных цифр не помню).

Answer (score -2):

Может ли у Вас не работать нормально IDE, потому что столько виртуалок одновременно работают? Ведь каждая ВМ берёт не маленько так оперативы (оптимально 2гб).