# Оптимизация IDE Android Studio (JetBrains)

Tags: java, android, ide, android-studio

Программирую под Андроид на очень слабом ноутбуке (ОС Убунту Линукс) под Android Studio (форк IntelliJ IDEA, если там можно выразиться).

1 ГБ ОЗУ, 2 ядра Intel Centrino. Всё жутко лагает.

Как можно оптимизировать работу IDE? Может какие-нибудь настройки или плагины лишние? 
Кроме анимации окон и каких-то иконок ничего не выключал.

Большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Поставь вместо Ubuntu дистрибутив Debian с какой-то оконной системой полегче, например, LXDE или XFCE. Заметишь, что скорость во много раз возрастёт. Я сейчас комфортно работаю на ноутбуке Acer Aspire One 722 с 4 ГБ оперативы (модель специально указал, чтобы ты увидел, что у меня проц ещё слабее). Всё работает изумительно. Лагов нет.

Comment: убунту не обязательно сносить, можно поставить xfce и переключить сессию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть такое понятие "девелоперская машина" - обычно довольно навороченная и уступающая геймерским только в плане наворотов с видеокартой и проч. попсовой периферией. На процессоре и оперативной памяти, среди девелоперов, не принято экономить.

Посмотрите [например здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/102944/java-c-c-c-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA-%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83) - что народ юзает

Answer (score 0):

Сомневаюсь, что что-то существенно удастся улучшить путём шаманства с настройками. Я бы всё же порекомендовал апгрейднуть ноутбук, ибо не представляю комфортной работы с такой конфигурацией даже просто в IDEA, не говоря уже о запущенном android-эмуляторе. А на удобстве программиста нельзя экономить. :)

Answer (score 0):

Можно наладить тестирование на реальном устройстве (подключить через USB, в меню "Run—›Edit Configurations", выбрать "USB Device") и **значительно** сократить потребление ресурсов)

Answer (score 0):

У меня точно такойже компьютер, на разработку не жалуюсь.

в андроид студии есть режим экономии батареи (отключает фоновую проверку кода да и еще чего-тотам и второй *java*-приложение которое появляется при компиляции)

Или ставьте быстрый дистрибутив *lubuntu*! работает хорошо быстро, в нем стоит *lxde* и минимальный набор пакетов , также ставьте боот менджеры отключайте что вам не нужно, чистите осину через *bleachbit* и *ubuntu tweak*, также советую запустить диспетчер задач *убунту* и выставить приоритеты какие вам надо.